# Why does my if statement doesn't work on my if block python discord bot development

Tags: python, discord

so I tried to make an if chain that let you choose from 3 different categories but when I started the bot it just ignored my 3 if after statement after the first if block was activated, can anybody help me with my situation?

```
if message.content.startswith("$Give me a q"):
await message.channel.send("Ok.")
await message.channel.send("In which topic would you like to get a q for?")
await message.channel.send("as for now we have q from wars of Israel, The founders of Israel and overall and the holocost (please choose by typing a number like 1,2,3 etc...)")

 if message.content.startswith('$1'):
  await message.channel.send("Great here is your q:")
  await message.channe.send(q_random('wars_of_Israel.txt'))

 elif message.content.startswith('$2'):
  await message.channel.send("still in construction...")

 elif message.content.startswith('$3'):
  await message.channel.send("still in construction...")
```

Comment: debug the value of  `message.content`, it's probably not a match. If it is a match, post the valie of  `message.content`

Comment: can you fix the indentation? I might be hard to say "why" without a fix

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect it should be written like so:

```
if message.content.startswith("$Give me a q"):
    await message.channel.send("Ok.")
    await message.channel.send("In which topic would you like to get a q for?")
    await message.channel.send("as for now we have q from wars of Israel, The 
    founders of Israel and overall and the holocost (please choose by typing a 
    number like 1,2,3 etc...)")

if message.content.startswith('$1'):
    await message.channel.send("Great here is your q:")
    await message.channe.send(q_random('wars_of_Israel.txt'))

elif message.content.startswith('$2'):
    await message.channel.send("still in construction...")

elif message.content.startswith('$3'):
    await message.channel.send("still in construction...")
```

This will force the code to evaluate all of the if statements.